# Valuation Method for CASH in S.06.02 QRTs

Tags: solvency-ii

Extract from the latest [spec](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32015R2450) for C0150 (Valuation Method) of S.06.02:

> Identify the valuation method used when valuing assets. One of the
>   options in the following closed list shall be used:
>
> 1 — quoted market price in active markets for the same assets
>
> 2 — quoted market price in active markets for similar assets
>
> 3 — alternative valuation methods
>
> 4 — adjusted equity methods (applicable for the valuation of
>   participations)
>
> 5 — IFRS equity methods (applicable for the valuation of
>   participations)
>
> 6 — Market valuation according to Article 9(4) of Delegated Regulation
>   (EU) 2015/35

My question is - which value applies to cash holdings / [CIC](http://rawfocus.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/eiopa-cic-codes.html) category 7?